# How to add multiples of a number and overwrite previous entry using js timing?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that continuously adds the same number to itself. Or simply displays multiples of one number every so many seconds with the `setInterval` method.

For now, let's just say I want to display multiples of ten.

I know how to get a regular while loop to simply display multiples of ten in a row, but what I want to do here is continually replace the previous text every time the function is called. I am trying to create a game and this is going to be the experience calculator. So it needs to display the total experience earned over the given time.

I was trying something along the lines of this:

```
window.setInterval(
    function writeExp ()
        {
            var j;
            while (rounded > 0)
                {
                    var i = w*10;
                    var j = j + i;
                }
            document.getElementByID("exp").innerHTML=j;
        }, experience)
```

This seems logical enough to me, but obviously something is wrong, as it does not work. I have tried googling various things like how to sum numbers in javascript or continuously sum, among others, but it is somewhat difficult to word to get it more centered to my needs. So this is the best way to get my questions answered.

Comment: Where do you alter the rounded variable, is it global ? This script if executed either will never enter the while or it will hang.

Comment: It is a local, but in reference to where it is, it is global, if that's how you want to look at it. The calculator exists within a function that has the variable rounded in it.

Comment: I just tried setting a true global variable with no value, and that still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of undefineds in your code, but general example would be

```js
var interval = 1000,
    result = 0,
    elem = document.getElementByID("exp");

window.setInterval(function () {
    result *= 10;
    elem.innerHTML = result;
}, interval);
```

or without global variables

```js
var interval = 1000,
    multiply = function (elem) {
        var result = 0;
        return function () {
            result *= 10;
            elem.innerHTML = result;
        }
    };

window.setInterval(multiply(document.getElementByID("exp")), interval);
```